# Swift : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason : unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb179f12260'

Tags: ios, swift, terminate, nsexception

I'm developing a simple app, but the problem stuck me a long long time!

I try to transit a model with segue!

The Upper one function is a `UITextField` as Action, however when I use it to open. Crash!

The other one can open the Model. Not being crash!

```
class showVerifyViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var verifyText: UITextField!

    @IBAction func setNewPinText(sender: AnyObject) {
        if verifyText.text == "zzz" {
            let viewController:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SetupPinViewController") as UIViewController
            let navigationView  = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
            self.presentViewController(navigationView, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func showTest(sender: AnyObject) {
        let viewController:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SetupPinViewController") as UIViewController
        let navigationView  = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)
        self.presentViewController(navigationView, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

---

```
[SoftPin.showVerifyViewController setNewPintext:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb179f12260
2016-05-23 18:19:58.372 SoftPin[2805:268743] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SoftPin.showVerifyViewController setNewPintext:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb179f12260'

0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001051c8d85 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000106f6cdeb objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001051d1d3d -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 205
3   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000105117cfa ___forwarding___ + 970
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001051178a8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   UIKit                               0x00000001059f2a8d -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
6   UIKit                               0x0000000105b65e67 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
7   UIKit                               0x0000000105b66143 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 327
8   UIKit                               0x00000001063ef6c5 -[UITextField _resignFirstResponder] + 298
9   UIKit                               0x0000000105c04a1a -[UIResponder _finishResignFirstResponder] + 292
10  UIKit                               0x00000001063ef4ef -[UITextField _finishResignFirstResponder] + 49
11  UIKit                               0x0000000105c04ac9 -[UIResponder resignFirstResponder] + 140
12  UIKit                               0x00000001063ef3bc -[UITextField resignFirstResponder] + 136
13  UIKit                               0x0000000105a97afd -[UIView(Hierarchy) _removeFirstResponderFromSubtree] + 161
14  UIKit                               0x0000000105a9802a __UIViewWillBeRemovedFromSuperview + 71
15  UIKit                               0x0000000105a97e48 -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview] + 99
16  UIKit                               0x0000000105b61afb __71-[UIPresentationController _initViewHierarchyForPresentationSuperview:]_block_invoke596 + 739
17  UIKit                               0x0000000105b5bdbe -[UIPresentationController transitionDidFinish:] + 111
18  UIKit                               0x0000000105d3938f -[_UICurrentContextPresentationController transitionDidFinish:] + 42
19  UIKit                               0x0000000105b5f7c1 __56-[UIPresentationController runTransitionForCurrentState]_block_invoke_2 + 183
20  UIKit                               0x000000010641e4c8 -[_UIViewControllerTransitionContext completeTransition:] + 101
21  UIKit                               0x0000000105b58f77 -[UITransitionView notifyDidCompleteTransition:] + 252
22  UIKit                               0x0000000105b58c88 -[UITransitionView _didCompleteTransition:] + 1344
23  UIKit                               0x0000000105b5b3f4 -[UITransitionView _transitionDidStop:finished:] + 104
24  UIKit                               0x0000000105a7e7ff -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] + 241
25  UIKit                               0x0000000105a7ebae -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] + 80
26  QuartzCore                          0x000000010a4723c8 _ZN2CA5Layer23run_animation_callbacksEPv + 308
27  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001079fc3eb _dispatch_client_callout + 8
28  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001079e41ef _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1738
29  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001051220f9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
30  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001050e3b99 __CFRunLoopRun + 2073
31  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001050e30f8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
32  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010985ead2 GSEventRunModal + 161
33  UIKit                               0x00000001059f0f09 UIApplicationMain + 171
34  SoftPin                             0x0000000104fcacd2 main + 114
35  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000107a3092d start + 1
36  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)

    libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Really need some suggestion!

Comment: Thanks for your advise!

Comment: There is no function named "setNewPintext" in showVerifyViewController.

Comment: @Eiko regardless of what the right format is, your edit made the stacktrace unreadable

Comment: @TimCastelijns Agreed. :) Didn't think it had that impact - it was improving on a suggested edit - but can't remember what I changed exactly here. Will check more thoroughly next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error tells you that you are calling `setNewPintext:` on `SoftPin.showVerifyViewController`, but the method doesn't exist. maybe a typo? maybe it should be `setNewPinText` (with an uppercase `T`)?:

Comment: Not really understand for your answer. I set a outlet called verifyText and a function called setNewPinText. why the method doesn't exist?

Comment: you call the method with a different name as how it is defined. It seem to be called as `setNewPintext` (as in `SoftPin.showVerifyViewController.setNewPintext("something")`, with a lowercase `t`). But as seen in your update, it is defined as `setNewPinText` (with an uppercase `T`)